# How can get data within a date range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, range

I have two date objects:

```
time_now = Time.now.to_date # => Thu, 22 Feb 2018
time_ago = Time.now.to_date - 60.days # => Tue, 23 Jan 2018
```

I tried to get data between these two dates:

```
EmployeeAttendance.where(day: time_now..time_ago)
```

But I can't find any data using this query.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `time_ago..time_now`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can't. In a range, the first element has to be smaller (earlier) than the last element. `time_ago..time_now` would be a more meaningful range.

Answer (score 0):

Another query format will be like,

```
EmployeeAttendance.where("day BETWEEN ? AND ?", time_ago, time_now)
```